# Funny and really annoying integer issue

Tags: c++, linux, integer, overflow, diskspace

So, I have the following code, I know it is broken somewhere and I simply cannot identify where...

```
static uint64_t get_disk_total(const char* path)
{
    struct statvfs stfs;
    if ( statvfs(path, &stfs) == -1 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    uint64_t t = stfs.f_blocks * stfs.f_bsize;
    std::cout  << "total for [" << path << "] is:" << t 
               << " block size (stfs.f_bsize):" <<   stfs.f_bsize
               << " block count (stfs.f_blocks):" << stfs.f_blocks 
               << " mul:" << stfs.f_blocks * stfs.f_bsize
               << " hardcoded: " << (uint64_t)(4096 * 4902319)     // line 50
               <<  std::endl ;
    return t;
}
```

When I compile it, tells me:

```
part_list.cpp: In function ‘uint64_t get_disk_total(const char*)’:
part_list.cpp:50:59: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
```

Good. And when I run it, the result is (line breaks added manually):

```
total for [/] is:2900029440 
block size (stfs.f_bsize):4096 
block count (stfs.f_blocks):4902319 
mul:2900029440 
hardcoded: 18446744072314613760
```

I know, that `4902319 * 4096 = 20079898624` ... [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=4902319%20%2a%204096&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) tells me it is. So how on earth do I get firstly `2900029440` and then `18446744072314613760` for the same calculation? Can someone please explain me what is happening here? It is above my comprehensive capabilities right now, and I feel, this is a tiny tiny issue somewhere hidden... `4902319 * 4096` should not be such a huge number for the application to go crazy like this...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try (uint64_t)(4096) * (uint64_t)(4902319). If you let your cast the way it is, it will cast your INT expression to an uint64_t result and not do a 64bits operation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you calculate `(4096 * 4902319)` which is calculated as `int` and it overflows.
Then that number is converted to `uint64_t`.

Try:

```
(4096 *  (uint64_t) 4902319)
```

To make it calculate as  uint64_t.

Comment: This explains it :) `uint64_t t = (uint64_t)stfs.f_blocks * (uint64_t)stfs.f_bsize;` is the correct way of solving the mistery ... Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting change from C++03.  In C++03, overflow in a contant expression makes the program ill-formed, and requires a diagnostic.  (I wonder why this was converted to undefined behavior in C++11.)

Answer (score 1):

Use *Unsigned long long* literal :

```
   4096 * 4902319ULL
                 ~~~
```

Before the calculation overflows.